# How can I make React app verify user token regularly?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a React app using Firebase Auth and an Express backend. I have React contexts set up for the user's authentication process and for the loading state of the app. Currently, when a user signs in, the following happens:

1. The app goes into a loading state
2. The app sends an API request to the backend to verify the user's token
3. The backend queries the database and then sets the user's custom claims with their permissions and sends a response with the verified token & claims
4. The loading state is cleared, and the app becomes useable

The user's routes / nav menu options etc are then determined by the user's permissions according to the backend - i.e, if a user doesn't have permission for a certain area of the site, its routes and nav menu items are not loaded.

My authentication context is as follows:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
/**
 * auth = getAuth()
 * provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
 */
import { auth, provider } from "providers/firebase";
import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithPopup,
  signOut as firebaseSignOut
} from "firebase/auth";
import { api } from "providers/axios";
import { useLoading } from "providers/loading";

const UserContext = createContext(null);
export const useAuth = () => useContext(UserContext);

const verifyToken = (token) =>
  api({
    method: "post",
    url: "/user/auth",
    headers: {
      token
    }
  });

const UserProvider = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const { loading, setLoading } = useLoading();

  const signIn = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      console.log("auth signInWithPopup", result.user.email);
    } catch (e) {
      setUser(null);
      console.error(e);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const signOut = async () => {
    let userSigningOut = user;
    try {
      await firebaseSignOut(auth);
      setUser(null);
      console.log("signed out");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    } finally {
      return (userSigningOut = null);
    }
  };

  const verifyUser = async (user) => {
    try {
      if (!user) {
        throw "no user";
      }

      const token = await getAuth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
      if (!token) {
        throw "no token";
      }

      const jwt = await getAuth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult();
      if (!jwt) {
        throw "no jwt";
      }

      const verifyTokenResponse = await verifyToken(token);
      if (verifyTokenResponse.data.role !== jwt.claims.role) {
        throw "role level claims mismatch";
      } else {
        user.verifiedToken = verifyTokenResponse.data;
        console.log(`User ${user.uid} verified`);
        setUser(user);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      signOut();
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        if (user) {
          console.log("onAuthStateChanged", user?.email);
          await verifyUser(user);
        } else {
          throw "no user";
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        signIn,
        signOut,
        user
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default UserProvider;
```

The problem is that if the user or their permissions are modified, the changes are not reflected in the app until the user performs a hard refresh.

What I'd like to achieve is for the user's token to be re-verified via the backend upon every page change (or similar) and then if their permissions etc have changed, the app then rerenders reflecting the changes. I think this could be achieved by triggering a rerender of a certain part of UserContext after taking it out of the main function, but I'm not sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: This seems like the wrong way to approach the problem. If your backend can verify the token on each action/request from the client the client will never be able to do something it shouldn't. Not sure how you are generating your tokens, but another thing you can do is shorten the validity of the token. That way the client will have to get a new token every 5, 10, 30, 60 minutes or whatever you find suitable.

Comment: Have you considered using a Realtime Database node or Cloud Firestore document that contains the user's roles? When the roles in that document are updated (which can be discovered using a real-time listener), then go and fetch the fresh token with the right permissions attached to the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [@samthecodingman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512946/how-can-i-make-react-app-verify-user-token-regularly#comment131533754_74512946), I added another state for the user's database entry and have achieved the desired outcome with the following changes to UserProvider:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        if (user) {
            const userDataRef = ref(db, `/users/${user.uid}`);
            return onValue(userDataRef, async snapshot => {
                await verifyUser(user);
                setUserData(snapshot.val());
            })
        }
    }, [user]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        signIn,
        signOut,
        user,
        userData
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
```

Comment: Don't forget the `return` statement for `return onValue(...)` so you properly unsubscribe the listener.